# prepending a string for a variable function call

Tags: php, php-5.6

PHP supports [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). eg. if `$str == 'testfunc';` then `$str();` calls `testfunc()`. I'd like to use this to test a bunch of functions like `funcname()` and `prefix_funcname()`. I was thinking I could do something like...

`${$prefix . 'funcname'}` doesn't work. That gives this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: funcname

Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

I've tried several other variations with no success. I'd prefer to do it all in one line instead of doing `$funcname = $prefix . $functname;` $funcname();`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are looking for: `call_user_func()`

Comment: Two lines or @Rizier123 way are the only ways as it is a _variable_ function not a _string_ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this with PHP 5.6 so the right answer is to use either the two lines (you can actually put them on the same line if you really feel the need) or [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

Like many others questions asking how work around syntax limitations to get things done in one go, the [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) fixes things right up in PHP 7 where you can use:

```
($prefix . 'funcname')();
```

This RFC is grossly under-appreciated.

---

Here's the thing, you *can* actually do what you're trying to do in earlier versions.

Kinda.

**Warning: This is disgusting. Use at your own risk of retribution from other programmers.**

```
${${$prefix . 'funcname'} = $prefix . 'funcname'}();
```

It's absolutely horrid, but it works in all supported versions of PHP (and likely earlier, I didn't bother trying.)

For the sake of explaining it all let's say `$prefix = "prefix_";`.

First `${$prefix . 'funcname'}` creates a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (don't use these) that resolves to `$prefix_funcname`.

So

```
${$prefix . 'funcname'} = $prefix . 'funcname'
```

works out to

```
$prefix_funcname = "prefix_funcname"
```

And because [*the value of an assignment expression is the value assigned*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) that outermost `${...}` gets the value `"prefix_funcname"` and gives you again a variable variable resolving to `$prefix_funcname` which we've already given the value `"prefix_funcname"`.

Leaving you with a variable function call to `prefix_funcname()`.

*Please don't do this.*